# PHP MySQL Select Length Error

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, lamp

A MySQL database houses 11,000+ rows and 3 assigned columns:  prices, UPC codes, and descriptions. Running LAMP on the same machine (Ubuntu 18.04), I am using PHP to grab each column of the database on page load and echo it into javascript arrays that are then searched by the user in a text box. The only problem is that my query only lets me select 644 items before it then loads nothing. This is a problem because 10,356+ rows are not being displayed. 
php file:

```
<?php
        session_start();
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sys.pds limit 644;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pds_code[] =  $row["Code"];
    $pds_desc[] =  $row['Description'];
    $pds_prce[] =  $row["Price"];
    }
}
$sqlDesc = json_encode($pds_desc);
$sqlPrice = json_encode($pds_prce);
$sqlCode = json_encode($pds_code);
echo "pds_descs = ". $sqlDesc . ";\n";
echo "pds_codes = ". $sqlCode . ";\n";
echo "pds_Prices = ". $sqlPrice . ";\n";

?>
```

Returns (from Chrome console):

> pds_descs = ["desc1","desc2","etc..."]; 
>   pds_codes = ["code1","code2","etc..."]; 
>   pds_Prices = ["price1","price2","etc..."];

When the limit is set to 645 (or removed) the arrays become:

> pds_descs = ; <--What triggers the error in the console 
>   pds_codes = ["code1","code2","etc..."]; 
>   pds_Prices = ["price1","price2","etc..."];

**It gets more interesting** Since the "Description" column is the only one not receiving anything, I tried referencing the column by number instead of name, replacing

```
$pds_desc[] =  $row['Description'];
```

with

```
$pds_desc[] =  $row[0];
```

*0 is the correct row for "Description". Instead of throwing the same output, is fills a small (20-30 row) array filled with null:

> pds_descs = [null,null,null,...]; 
>   pds_codes = ["code1","code2","etc..."]; 
>   pds_Prices = ["price1","price2","etc..."];

**How do I fix to load the full 11,000+ database into its arrays in js to remove the 644 limit**? I read about using Ajax to search client-->server instead of sideloading the database to the client on load but haven't ever used it and feel like this is still an avenue to explore. I also read about increasing the memory to MySQL/PHP but after much effort and modifying php.ini and my.cnf still nothing happened.

Comment: `json_encode($pds_desc);` is returning false. Try checking the array before running the `json_encode` function and see where is the error.

Comment: My guess is that you have an invalid character, like `$str = "\xF0";json_encode([$str]);` will return false;

Comment: everything shows up via `echo print_r($pds_desc);` Is it then the `$sqlDesc = json_encode($pds_desc);`?

Comment: you have SELECT * FROM sys.pds limit 644 limits to 644 records, it won't select anything beyond that. Get rid of limit 644 if you want to select all the records.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte The display errors print `session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at  [] in []) on line []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that entry 645 contained non-ASCII letters which broke the json_encode(); statement. 
To solve this, I ran a query in MYSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.pds 
WHERE Description <> CONVERT(Description USING ASCII);
```

This brought up a list of entries non in compliance with ASCII (I had 8 entries) to which I modified the element normal alphanumeric characters and applied. After a refresh of the chrome webpage all 11,745 rows could be loaded!